# how to get list of product under categoryID in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on an app in which if a category is clicked it goes to another route and list the product under that category.

This is my html template category id routes **:**

```
 <div>

    <p>{{category.type}}</p>

    <div
      v-for="product in products(category._id)"
      :key="product._id"
    >
      {{product.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

My script tag **:**

```
<script>

import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Product",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      categoryID: null,
      category: [],
      products: [],
      show: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/categories/${this.$route.params.id}`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.category = response.data.category;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        error;
      });

    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.product = response.data.product;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error;
      });
  },

 
};
</script>
```

Response I get in my console, the list of categories **:**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "category": {
        "_id": "6220db08e861f3dbbaf21e39",
        "products": [],
        "type": "3 bedroom",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

This is my list of products **:**

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "6256711a0e42d6c5ab370e9d",
            "category": {
                "_id": "6220db08e861f3dbbaf21e39",
                "products": [],
                "type": "3 bedroom",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "title": "galaxy s22",
            "price": 200,
            "stockQuantity": 1,
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "6256711a0e42d6c5ab370e9d"
        },        
    ]
}
```

my category api

```
router.get(`/categories/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let category = await Category.findOne({
          _id: req.params.id
        })
    
        res.json({
          success: true,
          category: category
        });
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
          success: false,
          message: err.message
        });
      }
  });
```

How can I get the list of products under a specific category ? I get the `{{ category.type }}`

Answer (score 0):

To get the products for a category you can filter your products :

```js
let categoryProducts = this.products.filter((p) => {
   return p.category.type == this.category.type
})
```

But perhaps its better to only retrive products of that category from the server, without filtering on js, if you don't need the products of other categories

i don't know your api but something like that perhaps :

```js
axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products?category=` + this.category.id, {})
     .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
       this.product = response.data.product;
     })
     .catch(error => {
       error;
     });
```

Comment: When you use filter method you have to compare, not assign values: `this.products.filter((p) => p.category.type === this.category.type )`

Comment: yes it's a typo

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to filtered out the products in the script and then bind that in the template as you are getting only one category object from an API.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // This is a mock data just for a demo (actual will come from API)
    category: {
      "success": true,
      "category": {
        "_id": "6220db08e861f3dbbaf21e39",
        "products": [],
        "type": "3 bedroom",
        "__v": 0
      }
    },
    // This is a mock data just for a demo (actual will come from API)
    products: [
      {
        "category": {
          "_id": "6220db08e861f3dbbaf21e39"
        },
        "title": "galaxy s22"
      },  {
            "category": {
                "_id": "6220db08e861f3dbbaf21e40"
            },
            "title": "galaxy s10"
        },        {
            "category": {
                "_id": "6220db08e861f3dbbaf21e39"
            },
            "title": "galaxy s30"
        }      
    ]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.products = this.products.filter(({ category }) => category._id === this.category.category._id);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{category.category.type}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="product in products" :key="product._id">
      {{ product.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm  just getting the {{category.type}} with this ,its not displaying the product

Comment: But if you run my code snippet, it is working properly. Showing category type as well as products under that category

Comment: Ok,  why this you use category twice, cause if I use it in my vue file it shows me type not defined

Comment: I  use {{category.type}} to get the category how can I get the products in filter if I use.... this.products = this.products.filter(({ category }) => category._id === this.category._id);  ..... it doesn't show anything

Comment: @jibzy As per the API response you shared, We have a category object inside the parent category object. Hence to access the type we have to use `category.category.type`

Comment: @jibzy can you please share a jsfiddle or codepen link .. So that i can look the actual issue you are facing

Comment: the category object is inside the data property "data": {
        "success": true,
        "category": {
            "_id": "6220db08e861f3dbbaf21e39",
            "products": [],
            "type": "3 bedroom",
            "__v": 0
        }
    },

Answer (score 0):

```
     mounted() {
            axios
              .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/categories/${this.$route.params.id}`)
              .then(response => {
               
                this.category = response.data.category;    
                })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                
              });
        }
```

By above api you will get category object which have products. so you don't need any other api. so now just loop using ***category.products***.

```
<div
      v-for="product in category.products"
      :key="product._id"
    >
      {{product.title}}
    </div>
```